# How can I disable the the adressbar with gwt?

Tags: gwt, webbrowser-control

In JavaScript when I open a popup I can disable the adressbar, so the user can't enter something.

Is there a similar option to disable the adressbar in gwt?

Answer (score 0):

Short of doing exactly that same thing and loading your GWT app within that popup window, no. You could potentially have a page that is NOT part of your GWT application open a new window with whatever options, then set the URL of that window to your GWT app's address. There's no way (AFAIK) to hide the address bar in the current window.

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked in this area much. Actually I could not understand whether you are trying to disable the popup's address bar or current parent window's address bar.

But what ever is possible in javascript that can be done in gwt. So if you know what to do using javascript for your requirement then you can go for [JSNI](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html). No need to look for GWT based solution.

Between I like your stackoverflow display name :-)

Thanks